# CSS, How can I do the exact opposite of this clip-path?

Tags: css, reactjs, polygon, clip-path

Hi guys I'm trying to make a arrow back shape for a container in my react project, so right now I managed to make a forward arrow using clipPath:

```
<div style={{clipPath: 'polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 70% 100%, 100% 50%, 70% 0%)'}}>
```

which gives me the following:
[exampleContainer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYlJY.png)

So I just want the path for the arrow shape to point left, thanks in advance!

Comment: polygon(0 50%, 30% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%, 30% 0%)

Comment: https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/ `clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 25% 100%, 0% 50%);`

Comment: Both answers gave me a very similar outcome, thank you, what exactly do the values of polygon mean?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your original arrow showing the coordinates of the points of the polygon in percentage terms. That is, % of the total width or height of the polygon depending on whether it's the x or y axis. Remember 0,0 is the position of the top left point.

[image]

You've got a couple of options to reverse it, you could try a CSS transform rotate. But to draw it from scratch note the points in this diagram:

[image]

and draw your polygon:

```css
div {
  clip-path: polygon(30% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%,  30% 100%, 0 50%);
  /* for demo only */
  width: 80vmin;
  height:100vmin;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```